# How is the Riemann integral over the real line defined?

Tags: probability, integration

I suddenly start to wonder this question. The main text I would refer to is Baby Rudin, and in chapter 6 about Riemann integral, only $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, where $a, b$ are real numbers, is defined.

In the exercise 8 of that chapter, it says if $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ exists for every $b>a$ where $a$ is fixed, then $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is defined as the limit of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ as $b$ approaches infinity, provided that this limit exists.

And then how is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ defined? I remember in the course complex analysis something is defined as $\lim_{R \xrightarrow{} \infty}\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)dx$. Is this the definition we use in default when we talk about the probability density function in elementary probability? Recall we say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ for a valid pdf $f$.

Comment: Answer: It’s defined as $$\lim_{M,N\to\infty} \int_{-M}^N f(x)dx.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you!!

Comment: Probability actually gives a good counterexample. The expectation of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) (pdf $\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2+1}$) is said to not exist but $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx$ exists and is equal to $0,$ so it must not be the right definition :). You may be remembering the Cauchy principal value from complex analysis, or you may just be remembering expressing it like this during contour integration, which is ok, provided you already know the integral converges.

Comment: @TedShifrin ... but, to avoid confusion, do not call that "the Riemann integral", but instead call it "the improper Riemann integral".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PDF case in probability ... the two calculations
$$\lim_{M,N\to\infty} \int_{-M}^N f(x)dx\quad\text{and}
\tag1$$
and
$$\lim_{R \xrightarrow{} \infty}\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)dx \tag2$$ are equivalent in the case $f$ is nonnegative.  It is only when $f$ is allowed to change sign that $(1)$ could fail to exist while $(2)$ exists.

We could call $(1)$ the "improper Riemann integral" and call $(2)$ the "principal value integral".